# jQuery-Datatables-parseFloat function Globalisation

Tags: jquery, datatables, columnsorting

I am using jQuery datatable to display the percentages in decimal values like

28.33

91.58

0.65

I use the parseFloat of these values to sort them. The problem comes during Internationalization, in French, German these values are represented as

28,33

91,58

0.65

The parseFloat functions ignores the , and displays only the number part. So 28,33 is displayed as 28 and 
91,58 is displayed as 91 and 
so on.. 
I need to retain the comma as well as sort the table. If I remove parsefloat, it is not sorting. If I replace , with . it works but I will need to have a comma. It would be helpful if someone suggests me a workaround for this.

**Code Snippet**

```
    $.ajax({
                dataType : "json",
                url : myURL,
                data : aoData,
                cache : false,
                success : function(json) {
                     var settings = {
                         tableSelector: getTableSelector(tab),
                         tableContainer : tab,
                         aaData : json.aaData,
                         iDisplayLength: 10,
                         bProcessing: false,
                         oLanguage : {
                            sEmptyTable: json.emptyTableMessage,
                            oPaginate: DataTablesUtils.getPaginationControls()
                        },
                         fnPreDrawCallback: function() {
                            resetArrowButtons(tab);
                         },
                         fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings) {
                             attachTableBodyEventListeners(tab);
                             DataTablesUtils.togglePaginationControls(oSettings, json.aaData.length);
                         },
                         fnInitComplete: function (oSettings) {
                             hideLoader(tab);
                             showTable(tableSelector);
                             showFilterBtn(tab);
                         },
                         aoColumns: columnRender(tab),
                         bSort : true,
                         aaSorting: []
                     };

                     var pagination = new DatatablesPagination(settings);
                     pagination.display();
                },
                error : function() {
                    showErrorMessageDetail(tab);
                }
            });




function columnRender(tab) {
        return [{
            // Column1
            "sWidth" : "50px",
            "bSortable" : true,
            "fnRender": function(oObj) {
                return getColumnIcon(oObj.aData[0]);
            }
        }, {
            // Percentage %
            "sWidth" : "90px",
            "bSortable" : true,
            "sType": "numeric",
            "fnRender" : function(oObj) {
                return showValueOrDash(oObj.aData[1]);
            }
        }];
    }


        function showValueOrDash(value) {
        return value ? parseFloat(value) : " - ";
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: @muecas I really don't know how to go about this. jQuery needs a number to sort but I can only give a number with a comma between it (which is not a number actually).

Comment: Why not giving a number with a dot?

Comment: @muecas we have a big data table where all the data is in English. The German users of the site would like to see the numbers alone in German format (90,82 instead of 90.82)

Comment: Can you post your DataTables js initialization?

Answer (score 0):

Do you **have to** use the legacy render function? DataTables 1.10 and later have [render methods with different signatures](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) that you can use to solve this problem easily. Looking at the [legacy documentation](https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) for this, I am not sure if it supports any different signatures.

In the later versions, you can define your render function to use the international version text for display, but use the sortable parseFloat version for sorting.

Something like this

```
//columns object
[{
   "sWidth" : "90px",
   "bSortable" : true,
   "sType": "numeric",
   "render": function (data, type, row) {return renderData(data, type, row); }
}]
//render function for the above column
function renderData(data, type, row){
   if(type = "display"){
      //return the unmodified data, or - if it is falsey
      return data ? data : "-";
   }
   else{
      //replace commas with periods, then parseFloat to sort the data
      return parseFloat(data.replace(",", "."));
   }
}
```